# Highcharts design advice - dual-x-axis stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a fairly complicated chart I'm trying to design in Highcharts. It is dual-x-axis stacked column chart.  Curious if anyone has had luck with [these](http://s284.photobucket.com/user/dsheets1/media/CostCurve/CostCurve_zpsp0gfytgf.png.html) sorts of charts in Highcharts.

It has dual X-axes and a single y-axis, and has stacked columns too.

Comment: highcharts is one of the best out there IMO

Comment: You probably should ask more than a yes/no question. This kind of question doesn't quite seem to fit here.

Comment: See [this ticket](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2303560-multi-dimensional-column-charts).